# Opening and reading txt files

Tags: python, file

Im writing a program and i want it to create and read a txt file. i researched a little bit and found out about `open()`, but i tried to test it out like this after i maed a txt file that simply said "hello" without the quotes, i called the program readnwrite:

```
open(readnwrite,r)
```

but im not sure like how to pick out certain parts of a program, or like if it can write a code into the file to access it later. i would also like to make something so that it can test if there is a file by a certain name, and if it isnt it creates one.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files documentation. you need to read it sometime.

Comment: @mdlp0716 As Lafexlos noted, you shall spend some time in existing tutorials. It is much more efficient than waiting to someone at SO answering or downvoting your question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open i tried reading here but it wasnt working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in function `open()`:

`readnwrite.txt`:

```
Hello World!

This is a test

Love from,
me...
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
>>> myfile = open("readnwrite.txt", "r+") #The "r+" specifies we want to read and write
>>> for line in myfile:
...     print line
... 
Hello World!



This is a test



Love from,

me...

>>>
```

If you want to write, use the built-in `write()` function:

```
>>> myfile.write('Hello, this is not a joke!')
>>> myfile.close()
```

Updated `readnwrite.txt`:

```
Hello World!

This a test

Love from,
me...
Hello, this is not a joke!
```

If you call the `write` function after calling `read()`, or just reading the file, it prints out your text at the end of the file, because the reading has brought us to the end. However, if you call the `write()` first, then it writes it to the top, **overlapping all the previous text**:

```
>>> myfile = open("readnwrite.txt", "r+")
>>> myfile.write("This should be at the top of the file now.")
>>> myfile.close()
```

Updated `readnwrite.txt`:

```
This should be at the top of the file now..
Hello, this is not a joke!
```

As you can see, the new `write()` overlapped everything in its way. Now let's see if it actually overlapped.

We are going to update `readnwrite.txt` by hand, and put in the text that was overlapped:

Updated `readnwrite.txt`:

```
Hello World!

This a test

Love from,
me..
```

Now if this is correct, this length should be `1` more than the length of the string `"This should be at the top of the file now."`. Why `1`? Because there is a new line at the end of each line:

```
Hello World!

This a test

Love from,
me..
```

Is actually

```
Hello World!\n
\n
This a test\n
\n
Love from,\n
me..\n
```

With the `'\n'`s as the escape sequences for new lines:

```
>>> myfile = open("readnwrite.txt", "r").read()
>>> myfile
'Hello World!\n\nThis a test\n\nLove from,\nme..\n'
>>> print myfile
Hello World!

This a test

Love from,
me..

>>>
```

Getting the lengths:

```
>>> myfile = open("readnwrite.txt", "r").read()
>>> myfile
'Hello World!\n\nThis a test\n\nLove from,\nme..\n'
>>> len(myfile)
43
>>> len("This should be at the top of the file now.")
42
>>> len(myfile) - len("This should be at the top of the file now.")
1
>>>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
# write "hello" to a text file
with open("mytextfile.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write("hello")

# read it back in
try:
    with open("mytextfile.txt", "r") as inf:
        data = inf.read()
        print(data)     # => prints "hello"
except FileNotFoundError as err:
    print(err)
    # if the file does not exist, will print
    # "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mytextfile.txt'"
```

**Edit:**

```
with open("mytextfile.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write("hello")
```

is the equivalent of

```
outf = open("mytextfile.txt", "w")
outf.write("hello")
outf.close()
```

except that it makes sure that `outf.close()` gets called *even if* `outf.write()` causes an error. Basically, it's the safe, approved way of working with files.

`FileNotFoundError` is the Python 3 exception for, well, file not found. If you are using Python 2.7 it will throw `IOError` instead.

Comment: thank you very much, just a few questions:
im not a pro at python or anthing, what is `with` andwhen it says `as inf` what does that part do exactly

Comment: just tested it out... it will make the file but it wont print hello, and it says FileNotFoundError isnt defined... i think its because im using python 2.7